# How do I compare month-year combinations in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, date, comparison, monthcalendar

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I have two pairs of numbers …

```
month1   # A number between 1 and 12
year1    # a four digit year
month2   # A number between 1 and 12
year2    # A four digit year
```

How do I write a comparison expression to determine if the “month2-year2” combination is greater than or equal to the “month1-year1” combination?  For instance if month2 = 1 and year2 = 2017 and month1 = 12 and year1 = 2016, the month2-year2 combination is greater than the month1-year1 combination.

Comment: Read this https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html and come back if you still have questions

Comment: Are you storing your month-year pairs in a string, array or something else??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What did you try? Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and "[mcve]" along with “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)”. Without evidence of your effort toward solving this it looks like you want us to do it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
month1, month2, year1, year2 = 12, 1, 2016, 2017
=> [12, 1, 2016, 2017]
Time.new(year1, month1) >= Time.new(year2, month2)
=> false
Time.new(year2, month2) >= Time.new(year1, month1)
=> true
```

reference: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#class-Time-label-Creating+a+new+Time+instance

Comment: You can also use `Date.new` but the idea is the same

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy and there's no need to create date or time objects.

```
def first_smaller?(ym1, ym2)
  (ym1 <=> ym2) == -1
end

first_smaller? [2016,12], [2017,1]
  #=> true
first_smaller? [2017,1], [2016,12]
  #=> false
first_smaller? [2017,1], [2017,1]
  #=> false
```

See the third paragraph of the doc for [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) to see how Ruby orders arrays.

If you also wish to know if the two arrays are equal, you could write something like the following:

```
def ordering(ym1, ym2)
  case ym1 <=> ym2
end
```

which returns `-1` if `ym1` is smaller, `+1` if `ym2` is smaller or `0` if the arrays are equal.